# Rotation gaps happened when blender model imported to Unity

Tags: unity

Rotation gaps happened when exported blender models with Rotation 0 imported to Unity.

below image is thumb of 3D character after importing blender models into Unity.

We would like to keep Rotation 0 though import blender models into Unity.
How do we solve this issue?

BTW, when export model at blender, checked "-Z forward" "Y up" "Apply Transform" on blender.

In addition, tried below url (addon module), but not fixed.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/319802/rotation-when-importing-from-blender.html

[image: you can see slightly gaps on each Rotation]

Thanks

Comment: This isn't off by 90 so it's not because of the difference in XYZ axes. Bone rotations are compared to the rotation of the bone parent in the armature, not world space so the hierarchy matters in both software.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your advise. Could you give me further advise for solving this issue?